# Xamarin android/wearable communication

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, wear-os

What is the absolute simplest way to send a string from an android phone to its paired wearable with Xamarin? I have viewed samples but whenever I try to copy and paste the code that allows it to communicate with the wearable, it gives errors. For example, in my MainActivity.cs, I have a sendData method:

```
public void sendData(String message)
{
    PutDataMapRequest data = PutDataMapRequest.Create("/message");
    data.getDataMap().putString(message);
}
```

There is an error on getDataMap() that says:

```
'PutDataMapRequest' does not contain a definition for 'getDataMap' and no extension method 'getDataMap' accepting a first argument of type 'PutDataMapRequest' could be found
```

I have tried:

- Installing the NuGet package "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Wearable"
- Copying and pasting from samples
- Looking at other threads on forums

There is very little documentation on message and data API, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are copying code from a Java sample, you need to ensure that you C#-ify it. That means instead of methods, you use properties. Sometimes bindings do not provide C# conventions, but they are proper cased. I would advise that you "Decompile" this .dll to see the exact methods inside.

Secondly you should double check that these APIs exist. Google tends to move/rename APIs quite often with updates to the libraries. For example, you might want to check this class first:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/PutDataRequest

The C# equivalent would be:

```
PutDataMapRequest data = PutDataMapRequest.Create("/message");
data.DataMap.PutString(message);
```